# laravel passing value from controller to model

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a base controller that gets certain default properties based on the domain name for every request. These include `app_id` and `language_id`.

What would be the recommended way to get these values set in my models, so that for example if I tried to create a new `Post` model it would have the `app_id` and `language_id` set by the values defined in my base_controller.

Kind regards to any response.

Comment: use __construct method in your model. pass those value when object initiated.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I have tried using __construct on the model and for testing simply hardcoded a value for the app_id but when I try and save the newed up object the app_id isn't getting stored.

Comment: is there any particular reason for having `app_id` and `language_id` injected in all models? instead create a model which has only these as properties and map those using eloquent. or inject those to the user object and pass that around

Comment: @jon: Have you checked $fillable property of class?

Comment: Thanks Ravi, but the fillable property includes the app_id

Comment: Thanks Cerlin Boss, I guess there's no reason to have them injected into each model, however I need a way to save them with each model. Therefore is your suggestion to create a default_model, but then I'm still stuck as to how to get that data into my newed up models for saving.

Comment: @jon: You did correct. one suggestion do not use hard code also declare private $app_id; write public function __construct($id) 
{ 
  $this->app_id =$id; 
} then you can access $this->app. now what is the problem? I think you will get app_id via $this->app_id in model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions to store your app_id and language_id, and get it from session whenever you need it.

[Check How to use sessions in Laravel from here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session)

Comment: Thanks theMohammedA, would this be a recommended best practise way to pass the data?

Comment: Depends on the data you are storing and how sensitive they are, also where are you storing. i.e. if you storing sessions in cookies (rather than db or file) then anyone can access your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__consruct` method as suggested in comment.

Here is another alternative:-

**YourController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\YourModel;

class YourController extends Controller
{

    public function callModelStaticMethod()
    {
        $data = ['appId'=>4, 'languageId'=>5];
        YourModel::passDataToModelMethod($data);        
    }
}
```

**YourModel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YourModel extends Model
{

    public static function passDataToModelMethod($data)
    {
      var_dump($data);
      // Write your business logic here.
      // $newObj = new self;
      // $newObj->app_id = $data['app_id'];
      // $newObj->language_id = $data['languageId'];
      // $newObj->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravi Hirani for your continued help, so when would I call the callModelStaticMethod() to set the data?

Comment: @jon: You do not need to call that method. It was just for example. You should consider code inside that method. By that code, you can pass data from controller to model. One question How did you get app_id and language_id in controller?

Comment: I am setting $data = Domain::where('domain', '=', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])->first(); in the constructor of the controller.

Comment: @jon: You just need to pass the $data when you need to call the model to save data.

Comment: I think I am being a bit silly. I don't even need to pass the data to the Model, the save method is being run from the controller so I can simply set the app_id and language_id on the newed up object from the save method. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @jon: ohh!! Yes if there is no private property of model class then you can directly save data from controller. I assumed that you need to fetch private class properties from model that's why you want to pass data to model.

Answer (score 0):

@ravi...just bit correction to your code. you can't call directly your method from model.

```
YourModel::passDataToModelMethod($data);
```

above won't work, you need to do as follows

```
$insertData=new YourModel();
$insertData->passDataToModelMethod($data);
```